# why this query is faling?

Tags: mysql

```
select * from temp where ssn not in (select distinct ssn from temp inner join
tamp where ssn,code_dars not in(select ssn,code_dars from temp));
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>       corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'code_dars
>       not in(select ssn,code_dars from temp))' at line 3

Comment: I would hope your typos aren't the issue?

Comment: this table is `tamp` or `temp` in join?

Comment: one of them is temp and another is tamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see several problems with your query... the one that is complaining about is that you can only specify one field to not be in another list unless you concatenate them some how, so either you do

```
 ... inner join tamp where code_dars not in (select code_dars from temp)
```

or you do

```
 ... inner join tamp where ROW(ssn,code_dars) not in (select ssn, code_dars from temp)
```

in any case I don't thing your query is going to give you what you want... (what ever that is :)...

1. distink: there's either a field called distink in your table in which case you're missing a coma, our you want distinct(ssn)
2. inner join needs a field to join the two tables... so you need some thing like inner join tamp on table1.field = table2.field

Comment: Don't forget that the concat method runs the risk of ("a","b-c") matching ("a-b","c")

Comment: @Brad your're right, corrected to use the row syntax... still doesn't work, but the whole query does not query as posted by mehdi

Answer (score 5):

It's `DISTINCT` not `distink`.

And the syntax for the [row subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/row-subqueries.html) is either

```
SELECT * FROM t1
  WHERE (col1,col2) = (SELECT col3, col4 FROM t2 WHERE id = 10);
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM t1
  WHERE ROW(col1,col2) = (SELECT col3, col4 FROM t2 WHERE id = 10);
```

Note the braces around the columns.

Answer (score 0):

The error its reporting is that your "in" condition is checking 2 columns at the same time, I'm not sure that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do

```
WHERE FOO, BAR CONDITION
```

You would have to either do

```
WHERE FOO CONDITION AND BAR CONDITION
```

Or something horrible like `WHERE FOO+BAR NOT IN SELECT FOO+BAR FROM OTHERTABLE` (NOT RECOMMENDED).